# Can Javascript's console.log() be redirected to a file?

Tags: redirect, console.log

Can Javascript's console.log() be redirected to a file ?
I am currently working on very simple node.js app that is hosted on Namecheap .
I can not see output from console.log(), but even being able to redirect it to a text file that I can examine by FTPing into my account later would be a help.

I tried using my web browser developer tools, but I can not see output of console.log() from the node.js app running on shared hosting by Namecheap. I *can* see it when doing so on own local developer machine.

```
const http = require('http');
console.log('Msg A: before createServer()');

http.createServer(
   function(request, response) 
   {
       response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
       response.end("<h1>Hello from Namecheap Node.js App</h1>");
       console.log('Msg B: requesting page from browser.');
   }
).listen(5000);

console.log('Msg C: after listen()');
```

Comment: You might be able to patch it using something like `console.log = f`, where `f` a function that writes to a file.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Nice! I will look into that and post back here regarding progress. I did, however, discover that I can instead use console.error() to write messages to the stderr.log file, which for right now gives me what I need, if not what I want. ( If you want to post that as an answer I will be glad to upvote it! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Carcigenicate put me on the road to find this solution on gitHub : https://gist.github.com/mksoni88/03f69c9c40bb65aa8bbb

which led me to hack the following code, thus giving me exactly what I need in the short term:

```
var fs = require("fs");
  
_log = console.log;
global.console.log = function() 
{
    var traceobj = new Error("deen").stack.split("\n")[2].split(":");
    //var file = traceobj[0].split(process.env.PWD + '/')[1];
    var line = traceobj[1];
    var new_args = [":" + line + " >> "];
    new_args.push.apply(new_args, arguments);
    
    // If we don't call _log.apply() below then we don't get console.log()
    // Why do we get the commas ?
    _log.apply( new_args); 
    
    fs.appendFile("myconsole.log", new_args + "\n", 
    function (err) 
    {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); } }
    );
    
};

const http = require('http');
console.log('Msg A: before createServer()');

http.createServer(
  function(request, response) 
  {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end("<h1>Hello from Namecheap Node.js App</h1>");
    console.log('Msg B: requesting page from browser.');
  }
).listen(5000);

console.log('Msg C: after listen()');
```

Also, I was able to SSH into the Namecheap site where this code lives, and use the tail -f command to interactively watch the output from the overridden console.log function:
`tail -f myconsole.log`

[image]

Comment: in response to your comment "why do we get the commas" its because it's an array and it joins by commas, so if you want to change that, tack on .join(" ") after the array ref

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're on Node, you can just call your application this way:

```
node foo.js > file.log
```

Instead of:

```
node foo.js
```

Comment: I tried that, both locally & on Namecheap. But Namecheap's CPanel would not let me do it, which is what I expected. I also tried it using SSH terminal but that command is not allowed & it seems Namecheap has disabled the node command since it is a shared hosting plan - thus forcing me to start the app from their CPanel implementation. But thanks for the informed suggestion, as I did learn from it.